# using camera.hardware reduces image quality

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-image

I have been following two links to create custom camera for my application. I have been successful in opening the camera. The problem is that it reduces that image quality. The links I have been following are these:

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/28/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-for-your-camera-in-android/

http://blog.rhesoft.com/2015/04/02/tutorial-how-to-use-camera-with-android-and-android-studio/

and my code is:

Camera Activity:

```
public class CameraSetter extends Activity {
    public Context context;
    public int CAMERA;
    // ImageView photo_setter;
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;

    public CameraSetter() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TypefaceProvider.registerDefaultIconSets();
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_preview);

        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        //photo_setter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imview_camera_setter);


        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);

            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
        }

        //btn to close the application
        ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
        imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

and my cameraview class is:

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        mCamera = camera;
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
            return;

        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
        }

        //now, recreate the camera preview
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
//our app has only one screen, so we'll destroy the camera in the surface
        //if you are unsing with more screens, please move this code your activity
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```

Can I increase the image quality using the same code or I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved by adding in surfacechanged:

```
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
            parameters.setRotation(90);
            List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
            for(int j=0;j<sizes.size();j++)
            {
                if(sizes.get(j).width > size.width)
                    size = sizes.get(j);
            }
            parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```